# How to use Cron Job with Django views?

Tags: python, django, cron, ftp

I want to schedule a job which sends the csv files from FTP server to my Django view, Which further manipulates the file and save it in database. I have never used Cron so I need a suggestion on how to execute this in the best possible way.

Answer (score 0):

Django by default will not provide support for async tasks/jobs that but the are multiple options to achieve what you want.
My recommendation is to use [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: Hi Moldovan, Thanks I am looking for a road map altogether.